# Can't store PHP-generated image outside of script; "result too large"

Tags: php, image

> Warning: file_get_contents(effect.php?file=test.gif&bs=&negative=1) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Result too large in C:\Users\[user]\Documents\NetBeansProjects\[site]\handler\img_replace.php on line 19

I get this error trying to access an image generated from a PHP script. I've been googling the "failed to open stream" and "result too large" errors for hours and I'm stumped.

This is the code for img_replace.php:

```
try
{
    $file = $_POST['file'];
    $ref_get = $_POST['ref_get'];

    $image = R::findOne(IMAGES_TABLE, "filename='$file'");
    $image->data = file_get_contents("effect.php?" . htmlspecialchars_decode($ref_get));

    R::store($image);
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

And this is the relevant code for effect.php:

```
try
{
    $image = R::findOne(IMAGES_TABLE, "filename='$file'");

    $mimetype = $image->mimetype;
    $filename = $image->filename;
    $data = $image->data;

    header("content-type: $mimetype");
    header("content-disposition: filename=$filename");

    $src_img = imagecreatefromstring($data);

    //manipulate the image

    echo imagepng($out_img);

}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    $message_ref = $ex->getMessage();
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

file_get_contents works when the target file is a normal image file, but I would rather not write files to disk to be read once and then erased (plus I would probably get the same error if I tried to do it anywhere but effect.php). Also it doesn't matter how large the generated image is since I even tried it with an 8x8 pixel test image and still got the error.

I've obviously tried using other methods than file_get_contents, including example #2 on this page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

I've also checked my php.ini file and the memory limit is 128MB.

Any ideas?

---

Edit: I was able to get the scripts to do essentially what I want, and it's probably better since now it doesn't go through the table looking for the same image twice. However, I still ended up having to take the intermediate step of writing to disk, and I still haven't solved the "Result too large" error. I also don't like how effect.php has completely different behaviors depending on a get value.

Here is the new img_replace.php:

```
<?php
require_once "../include/session.php";
require_once "../include/vars.php";

$ref_get = $_POST['ref_get'];

header("location: effect.php?" . htmlspecialchars_decode($ref_get) . "&apply=1");
exit();
```

And here is the code added to effects.php:

```
if($apply && $ref_base == "index.php?p=ucp")
    {
        $filename = "../tmp/temp.png";
        imagepng($out_img,$filename);
        $handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
        $image->data = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
        fclose($handle);
        unlink($filename);

        R::store($image);

        header("location: ../index.php?p=ucp&act=gallery");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        header("content-type: $mimetype");
        header("content-disposition: filename=$filename");
    }
```

Comment: What if you reimplement that piece of code using curl or sockets?

Comment: I don't know what that means. I did try the following code and managed to avoid the "result too large" error, but it seems to corrupt the image regardless of whether I use imagecreatefromstring():

Comment: ob_start();
        include "effect.php?" . htmlspecialchars_decode($ref_get);
        $image->data = imagecreatefromstring(ob_get_contents());
        ob_end_clean();

Comment: Ew!  Don't use include to read anything other than PHP code you want to execute.

Comment: It turns out I was still getting the "result too large" error with the include anyway, but it was hidden by the output buffer. :B

Comment: If there is another way to get the raw image data to be fed directly into the output buffer then it may work, but I'm not sure I'll avoid the error if I don't fix what's causing the error to happen in the first place.

Comment: Did you try to see what exactly is returned from the URL you are using `file_get_contents` on? Use Wireshark to do that. I suspect some `E_NOTICE`s or `E_WARNING`s filling up the output.

Answer (score 0):

After using my pesudo-solution posted above for a few days on my Windows localhost, I uploaded the scripts to my uni's comp sci server for testing in an online environment and was unable to get them to write files to disk despite setting perimissions on tmp to 777. Instead of trying to work around what's most likely a deliberate restriction, I went back to my output buffer idea.

The solution turned out to be deceptively simple.

```
        ob_start();            
        if($fmt == "jpeg")
        {
            $imagefunc($out_img,null,$quality);
        }
        else
        {
            $imagefunc($out_img);
        }
        $image->data = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        $filesize_bytes = strlen($image->data);
        $filesize_kb = (int)($filesize_bytes / 1024.0 + 0.5);

        if($filesize_kb <= $max_filesize && $filesize_bytes > 0)
        {
            $gallery = R::findOne(GALLERIES_TABLE, "filename='$file'");
            $image->filename = stripExt($image->filename) . ".$fmt";
            $gallery->filename = stripExt($gallery->filename) . ".$fmt";
            $image->mimetype = "image/$fmt";
            R::store($image);
            R::store($gallery);
            $message_ref = "Effects applied successfully. New filesize: " . $filesize_kb . "KB";
        }
        else if($filesize_bytes == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: Unable to create temp image");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("New file too large (" . $filesize_kb . "KB); replacement canceled");
        }
```

Granted, I'm still at a loss as to how to store generated raw data produced by an outside script, but at least now I've achieved my goal of never having to write files to disk.